# Late collision and duplex mismatch

Tags: half-duplex, full-duplex

I don't underastatnd late collisions at all (unfortunately the internet didn't help me). Please describe in **as much detail as possible** what is late collision, how are they different from normal collisions, how NICs detect it.

And the most important: how duplex mismatch and late collision are connected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discover duplex mismatch interfaces in the network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2420/discover-duplex-mismatch-interfaces-in-the-network)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a time window at the beginning of a frame sent on a half-duplex link when collisions may happen. That's also why there's a minimum frame size - collisions need to be detected reliably and the sender needs to be aware. The general problem with late collisions or undersized frames is that *some* nodes detect a collision while *others don't*. If the sender doesn't detect the collision the frame is lost.

*Late* collisions are those that happen after that time window at the beginning has passed, when there mustn't be any collision any more. They are a sign of some misdesign or malfunction - overlong segments, too many chained repeaters, duplex mismatches, NIC problem.

With a duplex mismatch - one link partner using half-duplex, the other using full-duplex mode - the full-duplex side (FDX) starts sending at any time it's got data ready, without checking the medium for any traffic or a collision (there can be neither in FDX). Depending on what the half-duplex side (HDX) is currently doing, there are different outcomes:

- HDX is idle: frame is received correctly
- HDX has just started sending: it detects a (normal) collision and aborts transmission - FDX receives a short frame (a runt) with FCS error
- HDX has been transmitting more than 512 bits into the frame: it detects a late collision and aborts transmission - FDX detects an incomplete frame (not a runt) with FCS error

You should note that half-duplex mode is all but obsolete. It originated from inherently half-duplex coax cabling and obsolete repeater hubs. For the last two decades, business networks have been using switched networks in full-duplex mode throughout.

Duplex mismatches can only happen when you force a specific mode on a port (e.g. *100 Mbit/s, full duplex*), disabling Auto Negotiation. That makes the link partner fall back to half-duplex mode.  Gigabit Ethernet and faster variants use full duplex exclusively (half duplex was standardized for GbE but isn't supported in real hardware) and Auto Negotiation is mandatory.

Comment: Wouldn't the FDX side detect the Jam signal, and detect the collision?

Comment: No. For FDX, collisions don't exist.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  Whenever I've seen a duplex mismatch on a host, the switch (which is full duplex) reports late collisions.  I know there *shouldn't be* late collisions, but I think the switch detects the jam signal nonetheless.

Comment: It's possible that a NIC even in full-duplex mode interprets a jam signal as (likely always late) "collision". However, according to IEEE 802.3 clause 1.1.2.2, "Full duplex operation does not require that transmitters defer, *nor do they monitor or react to receive activity, as there is no contention for a shared medium in this mode.*" Since there's no way a collision can happen, the NIC shouldn't actually report those.

Comment: Annex 4A *Simplified full duplex media access control* states "This MAC does not support the *half duplex* mode of operation so there is no need for collision detection or handling." - so, it's not prohibited but simply not necessary to report a detected jam signal.

Answer (score 3):

A late collision is one that occurs at least 512 bits after the start of the frame.

A device that is full duplex assumes that there will never be a collision, so it can transmit data at any time.

If a full duplex device (A) is connected to a half-duplex device (B),  A does not check to see if B is transmitting before it starts sending.  If B is transmitting at that time, B will send a jam signal, which is detected by A as a late collision.

Comment: So device (A) detect jam signal as a late collision only if device (A) already transmitted 512 bits? If device (A) (for example) transmitted 256 bits then jam signal recognized as "common" collision?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: And for device (A) it can be late collision, but for device (B) it can be "common" collision, am i right? It all depends on which device to look at

Comment: @Alexander A port in full-duplex mode doesn't detect any collisions. It just receives aborted transmission attempts with FCS errors.